# Subtracting of char 'a' when iterating over an array char[26]

Tags: java, char

In the following iteration

```
    char[] chars = new char[26];
    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++)
    {
        chars[string.charAt(i) - 'a']++;
    }
```

the position in the string must be `chars[String.charAt(i) - 'a']` instead of `chars[String.charAt(i)]` or a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException will be thrown. Why is this the case?

Comment: The `String` can only contain values between `a` and `z`... why is that the case? Hint: `'a' - 'a'` is `0` and `'b' - 'a'` is `1`.

Comment: It's not a null reference error, it's an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: Alternatively, to go with `chars[String.charAt(i)]`, replace `26` with `Character.MAX_VALUE + 1`. BTW—you probably mean to use `int[] counts = new int[…`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because if you try to use char as an index value it takes the ascii value of that character because it needs an integer. The array you have defined is of size 26. So any char with ascii value more than 25 will result in a ArrayIndexOutOFBoundsException.

When you do string.charAt(i) - 'a' basically you are subtracting the ascii value of 'a' from the ascii value of string.charAt(i). This helps in accessing the characters a to z from the index 0 to 25.

You should also make sure that all the characters in the string are lowercase else you will again run into the same problem.